# How to get cron expression given job name and group name?

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler, scheduler, crontrigger

I'm using Quartz Scheduler v.1.8.0.

How do I get the cron expression which was assigned/attached to a Job and scheduled using [CronTrigger](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/1.8.1/org/quartz/CronTrigger.html)?  I have the job name and group name in this case.  Though many Triggers can point to the same Job, in my case it is only one.

There is a method available in Scheduler class, [Scheduler.getTriggersOfJob(jobName, groupName)](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.5/org/quartz/Scheduler.html#getTriggersOfJob(org.quartz.JobKey)), but it returns only *Trigger* array.

Example cronexpression: `0 /5 10-20 * * ?`

**NOTE:** Class *CronTrigger* extends *Trigger*

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use Scheduler.getTriggerOfJob. This class returns all triggers for a given jobName and groupName, in a Trigger[].

Then, analyse the content of this array, test if the Trigger is a CronTrigger, and cast it to get the CronTrigger instance. Then, the getCronExpression() method should return what you are looking for.

Here is a code sample:

```
Trigger[] triggers = // ... (getTriggersOfJob)
for (Trigger trigger : triggers) {
    if (trigger instanceof CronTrigger) {
        CronTrigger cronTrigger = (CronTrigger) trigger;
        String cronExpr = cronTrigger.getCronExpression();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, am able to see my cronexpression back. BTW, a small correction in your code sample: `Cron**T**rigger cronTrigger = (CronTrigger) trigger;`.